# What are these spots?

Tags: engine, hood

Yesterday I went to inspect a 3 year-old car and saw a fair bit of white spots in the engine compartment. I've read that these could be coolant as we don't have salt on our roads here. Anyone know if it's a big issue? Is it a good idea to still go for it? The car drives fine otherwise, but I'm not sure what the liquid is.

Any advice appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it look like the drops would have come from one location, or is it more like the car went through a puddle and splashed water everywhere?

Comment: It looks to me like someone spray washed under the hood and didn't rinse very well.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The seller said the hood was never washed or cleaned. Somehow the hose looks so clean though.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm afraid I can't really tell. It's a 2019 Mazda 6. As far as I can tell from various YouTube videos, the bottom is covered.